# how to uglify javascript wiithout minifying it?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I'm trying to debug some errors in my JS.

I usually use gulp + uglify to get an ugly minified one-liner. Now I need to get the file with the original lines intact to know which line gave me an error - but I'd still like to keep an atmosphere of mystique. Is there a way to mangle the code to make it less understandable without minifying it using uglifyjs?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use source maps instead ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret - ok, looking it up.. thanks

Comment: Use Source Maps. Or Prettify the uglified code, and then see where the bug occurs, fix it and again uglify it or just leave it as it is, the variables would really be hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call uglify, you have the option to add the -b flag, which beautifies the output.

The common way to approach this is indeed via sourcemaps as mentioned in the comments though. The grunt adapter for uglify for example or https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2 (which is used by it) can generate those automatically for you via their sourcemap/--sourcemap option.